# Initializing sounds in starling from outside the Assets class

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, starling-framework

I'm following a tutorial on lynda.com detailing how to add sounds to my starling game (its by Lee Brimelow in case you have Lynda). In the tutorial, he embeds the sounds in the Assets.as class like so

```
    [Embed(source="../media/sounds/laser-shot-silenced.mp3")]
    private static var LaserSound:Class;
    public static var LaserSFX:Sound;

    [Embed(source="../media/sounds/mariah-carey-dubstep.mp3")]
    private static var Track1:Class;
    public static var Track1SFX:Sound;
```

Then initializes them in an init function, which is located lower down in the Assets.as class. Which looks like this...

```
    public static function init():void
    {
        skyTexture = Texture.fromBitmap(new sky());

        ta = new TextureAtlas(Texture.fromBitmap(new atlas()),
            XML(new atlasXML()));

        TextField.registerBitmapFont(new BitmapFont(Texture.fromBitmap(new komaka()),
            XML(new komikaXML()));

        LaserSFX = new LaserSound();
        Track1SFX = new Track1();
    }
```

My problem is that my init function is located in my InGame.as class and if I try to initialize the SFX there like

```
    public function initialize():void
    {
        LaserSFX = new LaserSound();
        Track1SFX = new Track1();
```

They show up as undefined properties. I assumed this could be fixed by adding

```
import Assets;
```

to the top of my InGame.as class but that didn't seem to do anything.

My more specific question is where do I initialize these sounds from my Assets class and how do I initialize them? Also, I have a class specifically for the Laser shot, shouldn't I be initializing in that class, or should it be in my InGame class?

Sorry if this question is poorly organized, just let me know what I can do to clean it up, or give more information if your having trouble understanding.

Below I will copy and paste the files I am working with...

---

InGame.as

package screens
{
    import Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2;

```
import com.reyco1.physinjector.PhysInjector;
import com.reyco1.physinjector.data.PhysicsObject;
import com.reyco1.physinjector.data.PhysicsProperties;

import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.utils.Dictionary;

import objects.Enemy;
import objects.GameBackground;
import objects.Laser;
import objects.Scarlet;
import objects.SnowBall;

import Assets;

import starling.core.Starling;
import starling.display.Button;
import starling.display.Image;
import starling.display.Sprite;
import starling.events.Event;
import starling.events.Touch;
import starling.events.TouchEvent;
import starling.events.TouchPhase;
import starling.utils.deg2rad;

public class InGame extends Sprite
{
    private var startBtn:Button;
    private var replayBtn:Button;
    private var gameOver:Image;
    private var bg:GameBackground;
    private var scarlet:Scarlet;

    private var enemies:Array;
    private var lasers:Array;
    private var presents:Array;

    private var lasersLayer:Sprite;
    private var enemiesLayer:Sprite;

    private var enemySpawnDelay:Number;
    private var enemySpawnCounter:Number;

    private var difficulty:Number;
    private var difficultyRate:Number;

    private var gameState:String;
    private var playerSpeed:Number;
    private const MIN_SPEED:Number = 650;

    private var gameArea:Rectangle;
    private var touchArea:Rectangle;
    private var shape:starling.display.Sprite = new starling.display.Sprite();

    private var target:Point = new Point(100, 100);

    private var touch:Touch;
    private var touchX:Number;
    private var touchY:Number;

    protected var sack:Image;
    protected var physics:PhysInjector;

    private var paused:Boolean = true;

    public function InGame()
    {
        super();
        this.addEventListener(starling.events.Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
    }

    private function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void
    {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        drawGame();
    }

    private function drawGame():void
    {
        presents = new Array();

        bg = new GameBackground();
        this.addChild(bg);

        gameOver = new Image(Assets.getTexture("GameOver"));
        gameOver.x = 83;
        gameOver.y = 130;
        this.addChild(gameOver);

        scarlet = new Scarlet;
        scarlet.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
        scarlet.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
        this.addChild(scarlet);
        setChildIndex(scarlet, 2)

        startBtn = new Button(Assets.getTexture("PlayBtn"));
        startBtn.x = stage.stageWidth * 0.5 - startBtn.width * 0.5;
        startBtn.y = stage.stageHeight * 0.5 - startBtn.height * 0.5 + 35;
        this.addChild(startBtn);

        replayBtn = new Button(Assets.getTexture("ReplayBtn"));
        replayBtn.x = 393;
        replayBtn.y = 287;
        this.addChild(replayBtn);

        //defines area scarlet can fly in
        gameArea = new Rectangle(0, 15, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight - 150);

        PhysInjector.STARLING = true;
        physics = new PhysInjector(Starling.current.nativeStage, new b2Vec2(0, 40), true);

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updatePhysics);

        addSack();
        addPresents();
    }

    private function addSack():void
    {
        sack = new Image(Assets.getTexture("Sack"));
        sack.x = 0;
        sack.y = 510;
        addChild(sack);

        physics.injectPhysics(sack, PhysInjector.SQUARE, new PhysicsProperties({isDynamic:false, friction:0.5, restitution:0.5}));
    }

    private function addPresents():void
    {
        for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var present:Image = new Image(Assets.getTexture("Present01"));
            //present.x = 0;
            present.y = 434;

            if(i < 4)
                present.x = i * present.width;
            else if (i < 7 && i > 3)
            {
                present.x = (i-3.5) * present.width;
                present.y = present.height * 4.5;
            }
            else if (i >= 7  && i < 9)
            {
                present.x = (i-6) * present.width;
                present.y = present.height * 3.5;
            }
            else if (i > 8)
            {
                present.x = (i-7.5) * present.width;
                present.y = present.height * 2.5;
            }

            addChild(present);
            setChildIndex(present, 1);
            presents.push(present);

            var presentP:PhysicsObject = physics.injectPhysics(present, PhysInjector.SQUARE, new PhysicsProperties({isDynamic:true, isDraggable:false, friction:0.2, restitution:0.5}));        
        }
    }

    public function disposeTemporarily():void
    {
        this.visible = false;
    }

    public function initialize():void
    {
        //LaserSFX = new LaserSound();
        //Track1SFX = new Track1();

        this.visible = true;

        scarlet.x = -stage.stageWidth;
        scarlet.y = stage.stageHeight * 0.5;

        gameState = "idle";

        playerSpeed = 0;

        difficultyRate = 0.3;
        difficulty = 1;
        enemySpawnDelay = enemySpawnCounter = 100;
        enemySpawnCounter = 100;

        enemies = new Array();
        lasers = new Array();

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

        lasersLayer = new Sprite();
        enemiesLayer = new Sprite();

        addChild(lasersLayer);
        addChild(enemiesLayer);

        replayBtn.visible = false;
        gameOver.visible = false;

        startBtn.addEventListener(Event.TRIGGERED, onStartBtnClick);
        stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, shootLaser);
        replayBtn.addEventListener(Event.TRIGGERED, onReplayBtnClick);

        this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, onTouch);
    }

    private function onStartBtnClick(event:Event):void
    {
        startBtn.visible = false;
        startBtn.removeEventListener(Event.TRIGGERED, onStartBtnClick);

        launchScarlet();
        enemies.length = 0;
        makeEnemies();

        paused = false;
    }

    private function onReplayBtnClick(event:Event):void
    {   
        replayBtn.visible = false;
        replayBtn.removeEventListener(Event.TRIGGERED, onReplayBtnClick);

        launchScarlet();
        enemies.length = 0;
        makeEnemies();

        paused = false;
    }

    private function launchScarlet():void
    {
        this.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH, onTouch);
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onGameTick);
    }

    private function onTouch(event:TouchEvent):void
    {
        touch = event.getTouch(stage);
        if(touch){
            touchX = touch.globalX;
            touchY = touch.globalY;

            target.x = event.touches[0].globalX;
            target.y = event.touches[0].globalY;
        }

    }

    private function onGameTick(event:Event):void
    {
        switch(gameState)
        {
            case"idle":
                //Take off
                if (scarlet.x < stage.stageWidth * 0.5 * 0.5)
                {
                    scarlet.x += ((stage.stageWidth * 0.5 * 0.5 + 10) - scarlet.x) * 0.5;
                    scarlet.y = stage.stageHeight * 0.5;

                    playerSpeed += (MIN_SPEED - playerSpeed) * 0.05;
                }
                else
                {
                    gameState = "flying";
                }
                break;
            case"flying":
                playerSpeed -= (playerSpeed - MIN_SPEED) * 0.01;

                scarlet.y -= (scarlet.y - touchY) * 0.4;

                if (-(scarlet.y - touchY) < 150 && -(scarlet.y - touchY) > -150)
                {
                    scarlet.rotation = deg2rad(-(scarlet.y - touchY) * 0.075);
                }

                if (scarlet.y > gameArea.bottom - scarlet.height * 0.5)
                {
                    scarlet.y = gameArea.bottom - scarlet.height * 0.5;
                    scarlet.rotation = deg2rad(0);
                }
                if (scarlet.y < gameArea.top + scarlet.height * 0.5)
                {
                    scarlet.y = gameArea.top + scarlet.height * 0.5;
                    scarlet.rotation = deg2rad(0);
                }
                break;
            case"over":

                paused = true;

                scarlet.visible = false;
                replayBtn.visible = true;
                gameOver.visible = true;

                //if(presents.length == 0)
                //  trace("your a loser");

                break;
        }
    }

    //addapted from "Shoot"

    private function shootLaser(event:TouchEvent):void
    {
        touch = event.getTouch(this, TouchPhase.ENDED);
        if(touch){  

            var newLaser:Laser = new Laser();

            newLaser.x = scarlet.x - 35;
            newLaser.y = scarlet.y - 20;

            newLaser.xVel = 50;

            newLaser.addEventListener(Laser.PURGE_EVENT, purgeLaserHandler);

            lasersLayer.addChild(newLaser);
            lasers.push(newLaser);
        }
    }


    private function purgeLaserHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        var targetLaser:Laser = Laser(event.target);
        purgeLaser(targetLaser);
    }

    private function purgeLaser(targetLaser:Laser):void
    {
        targetLaser.removeEventListener(Laser.PURGE_EVENT, purgeLaserHandler);

        try
        {
            var i:int;
            for (i = 0; i < lasers.length; i++)
            {
                if (lasers[i].name == targetLaser.name)
                {
                    lasers.splice(i, 1);
                    lasersLayer.removeChild(targetLaser);
                    i = lasers.length;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(e:Error)
        {
            trace("Failed to delete enemy!", e);
        }
    }

    private function makeEnemies():void
    {
        enemySpawnCounter++;

        if (enemySpawnCounter > enemySpawnDelay)
        {
            enemySpawnCounter = 0;
            enemySpawnDelay -= difficultyRate/5;
            difficulty += difficultyRate/5;
            makeEnemy();
        }
        else if (enemySpawnCounter <= enemySpawnDelay)
        {
            enemySpawnCounter == enemySpawnDelay
        }
    }

    private function makeEnemy():void
    {
        var i:int;

        for (i = 0; i < Math.floor(difficulty); i++)
        {
            var newEnemy:Enemy = new SnowBall();

            newEnemy.x = 925;
            newEnemy.y = Math.random() * 375 + 50;
            newEnemy.xVel = (-Math.random() * difficulty) - 5;
            newEnemy.sinMeter = Math.random() * 10;
            newEnemy.bobValue = Math.random() * difficulty;

            newEnemy.addEventListener(Enemy.PURGE_EVENT, purgeEnemyHandler);

            enemiesLayer.addChild(newEnemy);
            enemies.push(newEnemy);

            //To make an enemy with gravity
            //var enemyP:PhysicsObject = physics.injectPhysics(newEnemy, PhysInjector.CIRCLE, new PhysicsProperties({density:1.5, friction:0.2, restitution:0.5}));
            //enemyP.physicsProperties.linearVelocity = new b2Vec2(-20, -8);
        }
    }

    private function purgeEnemyHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        var targetSnowBall:Enemy = Enemy(event.target);
        purgeSnowBall(targetSnowBall);
    }

    private function purgeSnowBall(targetSnowBall:Enemy):void
    {
        targetSnowBall.removeEventListener(Enemy.PURGE_EVENT, purgeEnemyHandler);

        try
        {
            var i:int;
            for (i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++)
            {
                if (enemies[i].bobValue == targetSnowBall.bobValue)
                {
                    enemies.splice(i, 1);
                    //enemiesLayer.removeChild(targetSnowBall);
                    targetSnowBall.visible = false;  // Quick Fix
                    i = enemies.length;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(e:Error)
        {
            trace("Failed to delete enemy!", e);
        }
    }

    private function laserHitTest(laser:Laser):void
    {
        for each (var enemy:Enemy in enemies)
        {
            if (enemy.status != "Dead" && enemy.bounds.intersects(laser.bounds))
                {
                    enemy.status == "Dead";
                    enemy.destroy();
                    purgeSnowBall(enemy);
                }
        }
    }

    private function presentHitTest(presentP:Image):void
    {
        var i:int = 0;
        for each (var enemy:Enemy in enemies)
        {
            if (enemy.status != "Dead" && enemy.bounds.intersects(presentP.bounds))
                {
                    enemy.status == "Dead";
                    enemy.destroy();
                    purgeSnowBall(enemy);

                    //purgePresents();
                    //var presentPhys:PhysicsObject = physics.injectPhysics(presentP, PhysInjector.SQUARE, new PhysicsProperties({isDynamic:true, friction:0.2, restitution:0.5}));

                    clearPhysics(presentP);
                    presentP.visible = false; //works but is only a cheap hack


                }i++;
        }
    }

    private function purgePresents():void
    {
        //  present.removeEventListener(Laser.PURGE_EVENT, purgeLaserHandler);
        var i:int = 0;
        for each (var present:Image in presents)
        {
            if (present.x < -10)
            {
                clearPhysics(present);
                //removeChild(present, true);   //Causes Crash in DynamicRegistration.changePropertyOnRegistrationPoint because no parent class
                present.visible = false;        //Quick fix
                presents = presents.splice(i, 1);

                // 1. Clear current present of physics
                // 2. Make current present invisible (or remove from stage)
                // 3. Remove current present from presents array
            }
            else if(present.y > stage.stageHeight)
            {
                clearPhysics(present);
                //removeChild(present, true);
                present.visible = false;
                presents = presents.splice(i, 1);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    private function updatePhysics():void
    {
        physics.update();           
    }

    public function clearPhysics(present:Object):void
    {
        //removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updatePhysics);
        if(physics.bodies.indexOf(present) != -1)
            physics.removePhysics(present); 
        trace("removing physi");
    }

    private function update():void
    {
        trace(presents.length);


        for each (var enemy:Enemy in enemies)
        {
            enemy.update();
        }

        for each (var present:Image in presents)
        {
            presentHitTest(present);
        }

        purgePresents();

        for each (var laser:Laser in lasers)
        {
            laser.update();
            laserHitTest(laser);
        }

        if (enemies.length > 15)
        {
            gameState = "over";
        }
        if(!paused)
            makeEnemies();
    }
    //addapted from "Shoot"
}
```

}

---

Assets.as

package
{

```
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.utils.Dictionary;

import starling.textures.Texture;
import starling.textures.TextureAtlas;

public class Assets
{
    [Embed(source="../media/sounds/laser-shot-silenced.mp3")]
    private static var LaserSound:Class;
    public static var LaserSFX:Sound;

    [Embed(source="../media/sounds/mariah-carey-dubstep.mp3")]
    private static var Track1:Class;
    public static var Track1SFX:Sound;

    [Embed(source="../media/graphics/bgWelcome.png")]
    public static const BgWelcome:Class;

    [Embed(source="../media/graphics/bgInGame.png")]
    public static const BgInGame:Class;

    [Embed(source="../media/graphics/welcome_scarlet.png")]
    public static const WelcomeScarlet:Class;

    [Embed(source="../media/graphics/welcome_title.png")]
    public static const WelcomeTitle:Class;

    [Embed(source="../media/graphics/welcome_startButton.png")]
    public static const WelcomeStartBtn:Class;

    [Embed(source="../media/graphics/inGame_playButton.png")]
    public static const PlayBtn:Class;

    [Embed(source="../media/graphics/inGame_replayButton.png")]
    public static const ReplayBtn:Class;

    [Embed(source="../media/graphics/gameOver.png")]
    public static const GameOver:Class;

    [Embed(source="../media/graphics/present01.png")]
    public static const Present01:Class;

    [Embed(source="../media/graphics/sack.png")]
    public static const Sack:Class;

    [Embed(source="../media/graphics/snowBall.png")]
    public static const SnowBall:Class;

    [Embed(source="../media/graphics/laser.png")]
    public static const Laser:Class;

    private static var gameTextures:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    private static var gameTextureAtlas:TextureAtlas;

    [Embed(source="../media/graphics/mySpritesheet.png")]
    public static const AtlasTextureGame:Class;

    [Embed(source="../media/graphics/mySpritesheet.xml", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
    public static const AtlasXmlGame:Class;

    public static function getAtlas():TextureAtlas
    {
        if(gameTextureAtlas == null)
        {
            var texture:Texture = getTexture("AtlasTextureGame");
            var xml:XML = XML(new AtlasXmlGame());
            gameTextureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(texture, xml);
        }
        return gameTextureAtlas;
    }

    public static function getTexture(name:String):Texture
    {
        if (gameTextures[name] == undefined)
        {
            var bitmap:Bitmap = new Assets[name]();
            gameTextures[name] = Texture.fromBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        return gameTextures[name];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Tutorials often show the quick and easy way. Professional applications do not embed sounds and assets because they make the app size too big. It is shown in tutorials not because it's the right way but because it's the easy way. Anyway they are all static so access them by name of class + "." + name, ex: Assets.PlayBtn, Assets.LaserSound, etc.

Comment: @BotMaster that sounds like an answer. Why don't you add it as an answer?

Comment: because I also give a negative opinion on the method used (embedding)

Comment: @BotMaster Thanks for the response. I know how to call the sound... but not where or how to initialize it in the context of my program. If you reread the question, you'll find it's all about initialization.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I figured it out. My game heavily borrows from Hungry Hero (http://www.hungryherogame.com/) so I downloaded the source code and copied what he did.

Which was creating a separate sound asset manager class and initializing within that class like so...

package 
{
    import flash.media.Sound;

```
public class Sounds
{
    [Embed(source="../media/sounds/laser-shot-silenced.mp3")]
    public static const SND_LASER:Class;

    [Embed(source="../media/sounds/mariah-carey-dubstep.mp3")]
    public static const SND_TRACK1:Class;


    //Initializing the sounds
    public static var sndLaser:Sound = new Sounds.SND_LASER() as Sound;
    public static var sndTrack1:Sound = new Sounds.SND_TRACK1() as Sound;

    //Sound Muting
    public static var muted:Boolean = false;
}
```

}

And then calling the sound within my InGame class like so...

```
            if (!Sounds.muted) Sounds.sndLaser.play();
```

And of course remembering to import the right mixer...

```
import flash.media.SoundMixer;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the tutorial you were following tried to make everything very easy but but doing so it made it also a bit confusing because it did not explain how and why it worked. So let's extend on it and make your Assets class a bit more flexible and useful.

Your Assets class has 2 static methods to get and access your textures and textureatlses. Those methods can be accessed from anywhere as you do it by writing for example:

```
Assets.getTexture("PlayBtn");
```

So let's just do the same for sounds.
First you'll need a new method in your Assets class and a new dictionary as well to keep your sound references. First the variable (added under gameTextures variable as you see here):

```
private static var gameTextures:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
private static var gamesounds:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
```

Now the method (added under the getTexture method):

```
public static function getSound(name:String):Sound
{
    if (gamesounds[name] == undefined)
    {
        var sound:Sound = new Assets[name]();
        gamesounds[name] = sound;
    }
    return gamesounds[name];
}
```

Now you can just get your sound the same way and no need for initialization. Anywhere in your code you just do this for example:

```
var laser:Sound = Assets.getSound("LaserSound");
 laser.play();
```

Notice that Assets.LaserSFX is no0t used and you can safely get rid of it if you want.

Comment: Ya, that makes a lot of sense! I just needed to know how to deal with sounds separately from my other assets. I think both this solution, and my solution are both valid correct answers.

Comment: @BotMaster user3106238 asked you a `question`. I don't see any answer. That's not respectful. Voted down without any explanation.